# Trying to mock a dependency, but its initialization code still gets executed

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I am trying to mock a dependency in my unit test, but that dependency's initialization code still gets executed. Here is my code structure:

```
my_project
|_src
| |__dynamo_connector
| |  |__dynamo_manager.py
| |__package_to_test
| |  |__process_message.py
| |  |__process_message_test.py
```

The `dynamo_manager.py` file looks something like this:

```
import boto3
import ...

# This is the line causing the issue
dynamodb_client = boto3.client("dynamodb")

def add_item_to_dynamo(...):
...
```

The class that I want to test, `process_message.py`, looks something like this:

```
from my_project.src.dynamo_connector import add_item_to_dynamo
import ...

def method_to_test(...):
...
```

And this is what my test looks like:

```
import unittest
from unittest import mock
from unittest.mock import patch
# The exception starts on this line
from process_message import method_to_test

class TestClass(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch('process_message.my_project.src.dynamo_connector'):
    def test_my_method(self, mocked_dynamo_connector):
        print("Hello, world")
```

My problem is that even though I mocked `dynamo_connector`, the `boto3.client("dynamodb")` line is still getting executed, which throws a botocore initialization exception. How do I properly mock the `dynamo_manager` class?

I am using Python 3.6

Comment: Don't declare it at the module level. Make a function called `build_dynamo_client()` and then you can mock that.

Comment: Alternatively you might be able to use `moto` (https://github.com/spulec/moto)